# Internet Explorer scrolling makes monitor go black

Tags: internet-explorer

when I scroll with either the wheel or the scroll bar in IE 8, the monitor goes blank.  It's not just IE that goes white or blank - the entire monitor goes blank and then goes back on.  it goes off for a literal one second or so then returns.  It does not do this in Google Chrome or any other program.  I have searched and didn't find and answer.  Have any of you seen this and know the solution?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I kinda want to see see a video of this in action.

Comment: Reminds me of the WinMe times... I had the same happening, when I was pointing to "programs" in the Start menu :-] (although it wasn't returning, had to reboot computer)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem right now.  It has happened before after an update and it is happening again today.  I will assume that there was another F****-up on updates.  windows 7 Pro, IE 8.0.7600.16385.

Turn off smooth scrolling in IE * Internet options | Advanced | smooth scrolling -> unchecked.  It fixed the problem in my browser.

Comment: Really? what system configuration have you got.. ? and are you using legit version of winblows?